# Multiple BSOD Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, memory, bsod

I'm using Windows 7 and I've gotten multiple BSOD errors when browsing with chrome or watching videos.

I've updated my integrated graphics card driver but it didn't solve the problem. I've run Memtest86+(12 passes) - everything was OK, I've also tested the HDDs - no problem, too.

I've disabled

`GPU accelerated compositing

GPU Accelerated Canvas 2D

Web page Prerendering` in Chrome but I've got another BSOD yesterday.

Can you help me diagnose the problem?

Here're the crash dumps:

**UPDATE:**
I tried Anthony Lee's suggestion, restarted Chrome, played HD video in youtube and I got BSOD again. After that, I tried watching the same video in Firefox, Desktop Window Manager crashed and shortly after that - another BSOD.

Here's the crash dump

```
==================================================
Dump File         : 081113-24585-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 11.8.2013 г. 16:08:45 ч.
Bug Check String  : DRIVER_CORRUPTED_EXPOOL
Bug Check Code    : 0x000000c5
Parameter 1       : 0x00000003
Parameter 2       : 0x00000002
Parameter 3       : 0x00000000
Parameter 4       : 0x83f657ff
Caused By Driver  : NETIO.SYS
Caused By Address : NETIO.SYS+29b29
File Description  : Network I/O Subsystem
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7600.16569 (win7_gdr.100408-1504)
Processor         : 32-bit
Crash Address     : ntkrnlpa.exe+45cab
Stack Address 1   : ntkrnlpa.exe+1227ff
Stack Address 2   : ntkrnlpa.exe+1218aa
Stack Address 3   : NETIO.SYS+5424
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\081113-24585-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7600
Dump File Size    : 131 072
Dump File Time    : 11.8.2013 г. 16:09:45 ч.
==================================================
```

**UPDATE 2:**
New errors, watching the same HD video in youtube in Chrome. The first is after changing the memory slot.
I ran Prime95 and got

`FATAL ERROR:Rounding was 0.5, expected less than 0.4.`

```
==================================================
Dump File         : 081113-20607-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 11.8.2013 г. 18:07:15 ч.
Bug Check String  : MEMORY_MANAGEMENT
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000001a
Parameter 1       : 0x00005003
Parameter 2       : 0xc0802000
Parameter 3       : 0x00002f34
Parameter 4       : 0x03055c68
Caused By Driver  : ntkrnlpa.exe
Caused By Address : ntkrnlpa.exe+df61c
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7600.21163 (win7_ldr.120305-1505)
Processor         : 32-bit
Crash Address     : ntkrnlpa.exe+df61c
Stack Address 1   : ntkrnlpa.exe+68b6f
Stack Address 2   : ntkrnlpa.exe+8a4f5
Stack Address 3   : ntkrnlpa.exe+45ab8
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\081113-20607-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7600
Dump File Size    : 154 624
Dump File Time    : 11.8.2013 г. 18:08:18 ч.
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 081113-22136-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 11.8.2013 г. 17:28:33 ч.
Bug Check String  : KERNEL_MODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
Bug Check Code    : 0x1000008e
Parameter 1       : 0xc0000005
Parameter 2       : 0x82bd91ef
Parameter 3       : 0x90de0c38
Parameter 4       : 0x00000000
Caused By Driver  : win32k.sys
Caused By Address : win32k.sys+b91ef
File Description  : Multi-User Win32 Driver
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)
Processor         : 32-bit
Crash Address     : win32k.sys+b91ef
Stack Address 1   : win32k.sys+843c
Stack Address 2   : win32k.sys+8586
Stack Address 3   : win32k.sys+cc2c0
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\081113-22136-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7600
Dump File Size    : 131 072
Dump File Time    : 11.8.2013 г. 17:37:47 ч.
==================================================
```

**UPDATE 3**
After updating NOD32 as @magicandre1981 suggested I ran ESET SysInspector and got another BSOD. I uploaded the new .dmp files.

```
==================================================
Dump File         : 081213-21715-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 12.8.2013 г. 11:29:12 ч.
Bug Check String  : MEMORY_MANAGEMENT
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000001a
Parameter 1       : 0x00041201
Parameter 2       : 0xc0019128
Parameter 3       : 0x4a408847
Parameter 4       : 0x8822e2f0
Caused By Driver  : ntkrnlpa.exe
Caused By Address : ntkrnlpa.exe+af10d
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7600.21163 (win7_ldr.120305-1505)
Processor         : 32-bit
Crash Address     : ntkrnlpa.exe+af10d
Stack Address 1   : ntkrnlpa.exe+b0971
Stack Address 2   : ntkrnlpa.exe+a8658
Stack Address 3   : ntkrnlpa.exe+27c3a8
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\081213-21715-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7600
Dump File Size    : 156 992
Dump File Time    : 12.8.2013 г. 11:30:47 ч.
==================================================
```

[.dmp files](http://we.tl/fHGbCpOaw4)

[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/32eK2r9h)

```
==================================================
Dump File         : 081013-20670-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 10.8.2013 г. 23:17:00 ч.
Bug Check String  : SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
Bug Check Code    : 0x1000007e
Parameter 1       : 0xc0000005
Parameter 2       : 0x98b8cbb1
Parameter 3       : 0x8f1db9e8
Parameter 4       : 0x8f1db5c0
Caused By Driver  : dxgmms1.sys
Caused By Address : dxgmms1.sys+16bb1
File Description  : DirectX Graphics MMS
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7600.16755 (win7_gdr.110202-1503)
Processor         : 32-bit
Crash Address     : dxgmms1.sys+16bb1
Stack Address 1   : dxgmms1.sys+1a20c
Stack Address 2   : dxgmms1.sys+31850
Stack Address 3   : dxgmms1.sys+32141
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\081013-20670-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7600
Dump File Size    : 135 248
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 080313-16816-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 3.8.2013 г. 13:29:58 ч.
Bug Check String  : SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
Bug Check Code    : 0x1000007e
Parameter 1       : 0xc0000005
Parameter 2       : 0x9456bbb1
Parameter 3       : 0x8bf5f9e8
Parameter 4       : 0x8bf5f5c0
Caused By Driver  : dxgmms1.sys
Caused By Address : dxgmms1.sys+16bb1
File Description  : DirectX Graphics MMS
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7600.16755 (win7_gdr.110202-1503)
Processor         : 32-bit
Crash Address     : dxgmms1.sys+16bb1
Stack Address 1   : dxgmms1.sys+1a20c
Stack Address 2   : dxgmms1.sys+31850
Stack Address 3   : dxgmms1.sys+32141
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\080313-16816-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7600
Dump File Size    : 135 248
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 072813-21278-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 28.7.2013 г. 17:23:26 ч.
Bug Check String  : DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
Bug Check Code    : 0x000000d1
Parameter 1       : 0x00032349
Parameter 2       : 0x00000002
Parameter 3       : 0x00000000
Parameter 4       : 0x94853dbb
Caused By Driver  : nvlddmkm.sys
Caused By Address : nvlddmkm.sys+2fdbb
File Description  : NVIDIA Windows Kernel Mode Driver, Version 307.83
Product Name      : NVIDIA Windows Kernel Mode Driver, Version 307.83
Company           : NVIDIA Corporation
File Version      : 9.18.13.0783
Processor         : 32-bit
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+45cab
Stack Address 1   : nvlddmkm.sys+2fdbb
Stack Address 2   : nvlddmkm.sys+108c95
Stack Address 3   : dxgkrnl.sys+1e50
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\072813-21278-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7600
Dump File Size    : 131 072
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 072813-24804-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 28.7.2013 г. 16:22:45 ч.
Bug Check String  : BAD_POOL_CALLER
Bug Check Code    : 0x000000c2
Parameter 1       : 0x00000007
Parameter 2       : 0x00001097
Parameter 3       : 0x0000ab20
Parameter 4       : 0x88b648f0
Caused By Driver  : ntkrnlpa.exe
Caused By Address : ntkrnlpa.exe+1211b6
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7600.21163 (win7_ldr.120305-1505)
Processor         : 32-bit
Crash Address     : ntkrnlpa.exe+1211b6
Stack Address 1   : ntkrnlpa.exe+8f1b5
Stack Address 2   : ntkrnlpa.exe+b95aa
Stack Address 3   : ntkrnlpa.exe+2412a0
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\072813-24804-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7600
Dump File Size    : 131 072
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 072713-26660-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 27.7.2013 г. 21:21:26 ч.
Bug Check String  : KERNEL_MODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
Bug Check Code    : 0x1000008e
Parameter 1       : 0xc0000005
Parameter 2       : 0x840522cb
Parameter 3       : 0xabe17c2c
Parameter 4       : 0x00000000
Caused By Driver  : ntkrnlpa.exe
Caused By Address : ntkrnlpa.exe+2482cb
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7600.21163 (win7_ldr.120305-1505)
Processor         : 32-bit
Crash Address     : ntkrnlpa.exe+2482cb
Stack Address 1   : ntkrnlpa.exe+249caa
Stack Address 2   : ntkrnlpa.exe+249e22
Stack Address 3   : ntkrnlpa.exe+428ca
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\072713-26660-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7600
Dump File Size    : 151 136
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 071613-17877-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 16.7.2013 г. 15:26:15 ч.
Bug Check String  : IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000000a
Parameter 1       : 0xedb12e5a
Parameter 2       : 0x00000002
Parameter 3       : 0x00000000
Parameter 4       : 0x83eccfa8
Caused By Driver  : ntkrnlpa.exe
Caused By Address : ntkrnlpa.exe+45cab
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7600.21163 (win7_ldr.120305-1505)
Processor         : 32-bit
Crash Address     : ntkrnlpa.exe+45cab
Stack Address 1   : ntkrnlpa.exe+7dfa8
Stack Address 2   : ntkrnlpa.exe+8191e
Stack Address 3   : ntkrnlpa.exe+7e399
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\071613-17877-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7600
Dump File Size    : 131 072
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 062913-21996-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 29.6.2013 г. 18:32:43 ч.
Bug Check String  : BAD_POOL_HEADER
Bug Check Code    : 0x00000019
Parameter 1       : 0x00000020
Parameter 2       : 0x883b8108
Parameter 3       : 0x883b82e0
Parameter 4       : 0x083b8104
Caused By Driver  : ntkrnlpa.exe
Caused By Address : ntkrnlpa.exe+1211b6
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7600.21163 (win7_ldr.120305-1505)
Processor         : 32-bit
Crash Address     : ntkrnlpa.exe+1211b6
Stack Address 1   : ntkrnlpa.exe+224428
Stack Address 2   : ntkrnlpa.exe+2241cd
Stack Address 3   : ntkrnlpa.exe+7d320
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\062913-21996-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7600
Dump File Size    : 131 072
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 062813-24819-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 28.6.2013 г. 18:04:41 ч.
Bug Check String  : UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000007f
Parameter 1       : 0x0000000d
Parameter 2       : 0x00000000
Parameter 3       : 0x00000000
Parameter 4       : 0x00000000
Caused By Driver  : nvlddmkm.sys
Caused By Address : nvlddmkm.sys+45b89
File Description  : NVIDIA Windows Kernel Mode Driver, Version 307.83
Product Name      : NVIDIA Windows Kernel Mode Driver, Version 307.83
Company           : NVIDIA Corporation
File Version      : 9.18.13.0783
Processor         : 32-bit
Crash Address     : ntkrnlpa.exe+463eb
Stack Address 1   : nvlddmkm.sys+45b89
Stack Address 2   : nvlddmkm.sys+499ea
Stack Address 3   : nvlddmkm.sys+854019
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\062813-24819-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7600
Dump File Size    : 131 072
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 062813-22885-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 28.6.2013 г. 13:18:51 ч.
Bug Check String  : MEMORY_MANAGEMENT
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000001a
Parameter 1       : 0x00005001
Parameter 2       : 0xc0802000
Parameter 3       : 0x00004556
Parameter 4       : 0x0a9f1409
Caused By Driver  : ntkrnlpa.exe
Caused By Address : ntkrnlpa.exe+df61c
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7600.21163 (win7_ldr.120305-1505)
Processor         : 32-bit
Crash Address     : ntkrnlpa.exe+df61c
Stack Address 1   : ntkrnlpa.exe+68b6f
Stack Address 2   : ntkrnlpa.exe+8a4f5
Stack Address 3   : ntkrnlpa.exe+45ab8
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\062813-22885-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7600
Dump File Size    : 131 072
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 062513-18220-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 25.6.2013 г. 14:25:56 ч.
Bug Check String  : IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000000a
Parameter 1       : 0x1bf242f2
Parameter 2       : 0x00000002
Parameter 3       : 0x00000000
Parameter 4       : 0x83ed0fa8
Caused By Driver  : ntkrnlpa.exe
Caused By Address : ntkrnlpa.exe+45cab
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7600.21163 (win7_ldr.120305-1505)
Processor         : 32-bit
Crash Address     : ntkrnlpa.exe+45cab
Stack Address 1   : ntkrnlpa.exe+7dfa8
Stack Address 2   : ntkrnlpa.exe+8191e
Stack Address 3   : ntkrnlpa.exe+7e399
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\062513-18220-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7600
Dump File Size    : 131 072
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 061913-25350-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 19.6.2013 г. 19:30:02 ч.
Bug Check String  : SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
Bug Check Code    : 0x1000007e
Parameter 1       : 0xc0000005
Parameter 2       : 0x95367bb1
Parameter 3       : 0x8f1dc9e8
Parameter 4       : 0x8f1dc5c0
Caused By Driver  : dxgmms1.sys
Caused By Address : dxgmms1.sys+16bb1
File Description  : DirectX Graphics MMS
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7600.16755 (win7_gdr.110202-1503)
Processor         : 32-bit
Crash Address     : dxgmms1.sys+16bb1
Stack Address 1   : dxgmms1.sys+1a20c
Stack Address 2   : dxgmms1.sys+31850
Stack Address 3   : dxgmms1.sys+32141
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\061913-25350-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7600
Dump File Size    : 160 392
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 052213-22042-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 22.5.2013 г. 08:59:03 ч.
Bug Check String  : QUOTA_UNDERFLOW
Bug Check Code    : 0x00000021
Parameter 1       : 0x868ebc78
Parameter 2       : 0x00000001
Parameter 3       : 0xfffff030
Parameter 4       : 0xff1cd6a2
Caused By Driver  : ntkrnlpa.exe
Caused By Address : ntkrnlpa.exe+85d69
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7600.21163 (win7_ldr.120305-1505)
Processor         : 32-bit
Crash Address     : ntkrnlpa.exe+85d69
Stack Address 1   : ntkrnlpa.exe+c18ae
Stack Address 2   : ntkrnlpa.exe+26d6ff
Stack Address 3   : ntkrnlpa.exe+a7daa
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\052213-22042-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7600
Dump File Size    : 160 216
==================================================
```

Comment: I believe i got similar issues. but after i force chrome to use window  flash instead of pepper flash, this issues seems to happen less. probably the pepper coding issues.

Comment: to diable pepper flash, goto       chrome://plugins/     in url bar, then hit diable at pepflashplayer.dll

Comment: Thanks but the problem seems to not be in Chrome only. Please, read the update

Comment: go start resmon, and check to see if you have a large portion of memory (>20%) is hardware reserved. try to re-allocate your memory slot and reboot a few times. ( if in any 1 attempt you observed this symptoms ), probably one of your memory (or the memory socket) is becoming unstable, (usually the hottest one). See if this help.

Comment: Only 3% is hardware reserved. I changed the memory slot(I have only one memory stick) - again BSOD(different code this time - please, see update 2) when watching the HD video. I ran Prime95 and got `FATAL ERROR:Rounding was 0.5, expected less than 0.4`. The BSOD screens started showing after updating the BIOS.

Comment: upload the .dmp files. Also run memtest86+ to check your RAM.

Comment: Thanks! Here're the .dmp files - http://we.tl/hb4dKgncIh. I'll run memtest86+ the whole night.

Comment: update NOD32. you use a version from 2011. What was the result of the memtest? some dumps show issues which maybe RAM related.

Comment: 12 passes - no errors. I'm updating NOD32.

Comment: After the update, I ran ESET SysInspector and got another BSOD. Here're the new .dmp files - http://we.tl/fHGbCpOaw4

Comment: a small question, how much memory do you have ? at least 4GB ? i just notice that you are running 2 core 32-bit processors ?

Comment: 2GB DDR2 - it's an old computer but I haven't gotten BSODs before. Do I need to add more RAM?

Comment: are the RAM timings ok? Check them with **CPU-Z** and compare the value from **memory** and **SPD** tab. Also install the Sp1, you still use the Windows 7 RTM which no longer gets updates.

Comment: The SPD tab shows that tRC should be 23 but in the memory tab it's 24. Everything else is OK. DRAM Frequency changes from 200.9 to 401.8 but the timings doesn't, is that normal? I think that the frequency change caused by AMD cool'n'quiet.

Comment: Timings are ok. have you tried to install the Sp1?

Comment: I installed it and also set the integrated graphics card memory to 256MB and so far no BSODs when watching HD videos or else. I'll do more tests but I think that the problem is fixed. Can you please add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: ok, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, the RAM timings are ok. So it is no RAM issue. From the dumps, I can see that you use Windows 7 RTM at a patch level from June 2012. In April 2013 MS stopped releasing Updates for Win7 RTM. So [install the Windows 7 Sp1](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-windows-7-service-pack-1) to get newer updates which also fix bugs.